# Segway RMP delocalizes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Folks,

I have a segway 50 XL as my robot's platform.
When the robot goes backwards/forwards, it localizes quick and well. But when the robot is turning in place, it quickly de-localizes, causing the robot to move in the wrong direction when ROS tells it to go on a a straight line.
I am using the segway_rmp packages, and the libsegwayrmp. I have not modified anything on any library, but I guess I need to in order to fix the problem. Maybe I need to find a better "magic number" for the base width (I'm assuming you have a base with parameter for the odometry)??? (modifying the based with on another platform helped me solve the problem)

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203460/segway-rmp-delocalizes/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-02-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See https://github.com/asisbot/libsegwayrmp/pull/1. There's clearly some inconsistencies based on the firmware version and the RMP model.

You maybe have to tweak those parameters yourself and build from source, although it would be nicer if they were exposed to rosparam.

A good way to tune odometry is using a sensor like a LIDAR or Kinect. Set the persistence of the data in rviz, and tweak your wheel_base and wheel_width parameters until you have good agreement between subsequent scans overlaid in the `odom` frame.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2015-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0